# Big Query pars_timestamp issue

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to use Pars_Timestamp function in Standard SQL and it parses with no differentiation between Am and PM below is my query and the result of both are the same which is not correct;

```
SELECT
  PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%B %e, %Y %l:%M %p",time)
FROM ( 
  SELECT
    'May 14, 2018 9:46 AM' AS time
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'May 14, 2018 9:46 PM' AS time )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%B %e, %Y %I:%M %p",time)
```

You can try it with your dummy data as

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%B %e, %Y %I:%M %p",time)
FROM ( 
  SELECT
    'May 14, 2018 9:46 AM' AS time
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'May 14, 2018 9:46 PM' AS time )
```

this will give you

```
05/14/2018 09:46:00
05/14/2018 21:46:00
```